# URL rewriting: Should "?" or "&" be used for additional parameters

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, query-string, url-parameters

I have the following URL rewriting rule (IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite module/ASP.NET) in place:

```
www.domain.com/page.html?id=1
www.domain.com/page/1
```

I want to add an optional tracking parameter, `p=1`, to the rewritten URL. Should I use a `?` or an `&`?

```
www.domain.com/page/1?p=1
```

or

```
www.domain.com/page/1&p=1
```

Both seem to work, I'd just like to know the "correct" way to do this to avoid any compliance/compatibility issues.

Comment: ?p=1 seems more logical from a reading standpoint.

Comment: I guess I don't know enough about how the URL rewriting works. At any point, would the ? for ?p=1 be seen as a "duplicate" in a situation where id=1 would cause ?id=1 to be generated?